# Glvalue refers to a base class subobject

Tags: c++, lvalue

There is one restriction:

> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the
>   storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the
>   lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the
>   object occupied is reused or released, any **glvalue that refers to the**
>   **original object** may be used but only in limited ways. For an object
>   under construction or destruction, see 12.7. Otherwise, such a glvalue
>   refers to allocated storage (3.7.4.2), and using the properties of the
>   glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined. The program
>   has undefined behavior if:
>
> [...]
>
> — the glvalue ***is*** bound to a reference to a virtual base class (8.5.3),
>
> [...]

How it is even possible that glvalue is bound to a reference to a virtual base class and refers to the original object simultaneously? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading that sentence wrong. The direct analog of the bullet point you quoted, for pointers to an object whose lifetime has ended is (§3.8 [basic.life]/p5):

> - the pointer is implicitly converted (4.10) to a pointer to a virtual
>     base class

So it's talking about something like this:

```
struct A { };
struct B : virtual A { ~B() {} };
int main() {
    B* pb = new B;
    B& rb = *pb;
    A& ra1 = rb; 

    pb->~B();    // ends lifetime of *pb
    &rb;         // OK
    A& ra2 = rb; // Undefined behavior. The glvalue rb, referring to an object whose lifetime
                 // has ended, is bound to a reference to its virtual base class A
    A* pa = pb;  // Equally undefined
}
```

Comment: Should be "*after* the lifetime of an object has ended and *before* the storage which the object occupied is reused or released". In your case, the storage has been already reused.

Comment: @GiulioFranco Sure, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems like a demonstration of the problem:

```
struct Base {};
struct X : virtual Base {};

int main()
{
    X * p = static_cast<X *>(operator new(sizeof X));

    Base & r = *p;        // *p is an lvalue in the restricted sense
                          // binding it to a Base & has undefined behaviour

    operator delete(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of a reference to a non-trivial `Derived` object: you destroy the object with an explicit destructor call and you use a reference to that object to access some functions which don't use/modify any state (*properties of the glvalue that do not depend on its value*). Since nothing has changed the memory contents, that is still a valid operation (only the cleanup for the object has been performed).

Anyway the same isn't true if the glvalue is bound to an object **before** its creation (lifetime begins when initialization ends): if you had a `Base&` reference and `Base` was a virtual class, that would be different: **you would be calling methods/functions through the vtable and that hasn't been initialized yet**. Undefined behavior.

e.g.

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual void hello() { cout << "hello base"; }
};
class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    virtual void hello() { cout << "hello derived"; }
};
int main()
{
    Derived* p = static_cast<Derived*>(operator new(sizeof(Derived)));

    Base& r = *p;
    r.hello(); // invalid vtable
}
```

[*A possible outcome from coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af7d1fa12719b532)